# How to center a text to a RadioButton with ControlTemplate in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I was trying to use ControlTemplate to make a custom RadioButton that doesn't have the little circle, but now I can't center the text to be in the middle, how could I center it, and I'm trying to use every way I can think of.

[image: The radiobutton]

The code of the ControlTemplate I tried to use

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
               <Frame
                    Padding="0"
                    BackgroundColor="#D9D9D9"
                    BorderColor="#877373"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    HeightRequest="100"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="400"
                    CornerRadius="20"
                    >
                    <Grid Margin="4" WidthRequest="240">
                       Here is a small code that hides the circles
                    </Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroupList>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#df6e57" />
                                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                                        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Check" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#F3F2F1" />
                                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                                        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Check" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateGroupList>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Frame>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I don't see the xaml that is displaying that text.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton#redefine-radiobutton-appearance). And you can set it like this:

```
        <RadioButton>
            <RadioButton.Content>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="xxx"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
            </RadioButton.Content>
        </RadioButton>
```